# Noise after resuming computer from suspend

Tags: suspend, alsa, noise

I hear noise in my speakers and headphones after waking up my PC. To fix this, I have to reload ALSA. Is there a way to fix, or at least to reload ALSA automatic after suspend ?

Oh I forgot, I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 and my soundcard is Creative X-Fi ExtremeGamer.

Answer (score 8):

You could add a script to `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` to run things when the computer wakes up. The scripts in this directory run at both sleep and wake so in order to detect which are which, the scripts are passed an argument to say what's going on. In your case, it doesn't really matter, but I'll code for it anyway.

Run `gksu gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_restart-alsa` and then paste the following into it. You'll want to make edits because I'm not sure how you're restarting the sound system. Just add what works for you.

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
    hibernate|suspend)
        # we don't need to do anything when it's going to sleep       
        ;;
    resume|thaw)
        # this is coming back from sleep/hibernate
        # ** ADD YOUR ALSA-RESTART CODE ON THE NEXT LINE **

        ;;
esac
```